How should I remove the molded stamp from a pipe where I need to put a slip joint?
I'm finishing up adapting my plumbing to a new kitchen counter install, and have just one more problem spot where I'm attaching to the garbage disposal (first photo).  I had to replace the bent arm that came with the disposal with a different straight end outlet tail pipe (thanks to the great suggestion in this thread), but the tail pipe has some raised logo/text printed on it right where I need the slip joint seal to go! (second photo).
I think this has to be the cause of my leak and wanted to ask about good ways to remove it, as I'm not sure i can find a different part that doesn't have the texture there.  Sand it down?  I'm wondering how perfect I'll need to get it and whether it might be extremely difficult to do so and worth pursuing other options.  Thanks!



FYI, whatever that white goo is has no business whatsoever on a slip joint. They do not seal at the threads, and if you're doing so you're doing it wrong.

Rotate the U-bend of the trap using the union joint 180 degrees so the slip joint arm section is longer and you are sealing on it where it's intended to be sealed on. That's assuming you left your glued PVC as in the previous linked question and only have that as the one degree of freedom in fitting this.

If you change the traps to slip joint traps there are more degrees of freedom available to make the parts fit. Actually, I guess you could rotate both the disposal and the union joint on the trap to have two degrees of freedom, and some other intermediate-length options; disposals are awkward (but possible) to move.

It's an S arrangement (trap adapter in the floor) so I like the first suggestion better IE rotate the trap and disposal so the arm works.  A standard $20 drain kit with one trap and all slip joints to replace everything in the picture would be the obvious choice, but I don't think you can get 2 inch ones ... can you?  And here with the drain in the floor the bigger traps are probably  a good idea.

There's a vent pipe (in purple) at the top of the tees where the traps tie in, so it's not an S, apparently. The vent makes them P traps. You jast have the "normally hidden in wall" drain/vent stack exposed here. Can't tell from the picture in the original post if it's an AAV or a real vent, but it seems to be a vent.

@Ecnerwal ah i see that now - of course!  this has been a lesson in thinking in 3 dimensions. thanks so much!
